# Trouble pushing changes from one branch to another in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio

I encountered an issue while trying to push changes from one branch to another in Android Studio. Here are the details:

Situation: I merged a local branch (let's call it Branch A) into my working branch (Branch B).

Changes: My current working branch (Branch B) contains several modifications that I've already committed.

Problem: When attempting to push these changes, Android Studio is displaying multiple commits that seem to come from Branch A.

Query: What is the recommended approach to push the changes. Do we need to push all commit history?